# How to do a search with django haystack and elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Here is my case:

Say I have these items as documents for search:

- FourTrax Foreman Rubicon GPScape
- FourTrax Foreman Rubicon 4x4
- FourTrax Foreman Rubic
- FourTrax Foreman 4x4

Now when I do a search for "FourTrax Foreman Rubicon" I want to get all of them as search results listed in same order as described above. First two because they contain exact same text and last two because "FourTrax Foreman" matches part of my search query.

How do I do that with django haystack and elasticsearch?

Comment: The docs look sufficient enough to implement this: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html or maybe you can post something you've tried ?

Comment: If I do it all as per documentation I only get first two lines as search query results. That's the problem..